# ROOT.war (war exploded) для IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: сервер, intellij-idea, tomcat, config

Пытаюсь собрать проект, выполнил команду mvn clean package, чтобы получить war exploded артефакт. В консоли отобразилось инфо о том, что сборка прошла успешно (и еще я заметил вот эту строку - Building war: D:\IdeaProjects\target\ROOT.war).
Далее я открываю IntelliJ IDEA -> Edit Configurations -> Tomcat Server - Local, а во вкладке "Deployment" написано "nothing to deploy" (скрин прикреплен). Есть возможность выбрать артефакт из "external source", так вот вопрос, ROOT.war это и есть тот самый скомпилированный проект, который нужно прикрепить в "Deployment"?
Если нет, то где искать war exploded? Спасибо[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Из какого каталога запускаете `mvn clean`?

Comment: Из каталога с проектом, там где лежит pom.xml

Comment: судя по урлу `D:\IdeaProjects\target\ROOT.war`, pom.xml лежит в каталоге `D:\IdeaProjects` ? Как-то не привычно видеть папку `target` в етом месте

Comment: да, pom лежит именно там.

Comment: папка "IdeaProjects" выделена под один проект, не обращайте внимание на название папки